# How to get a value with .ToFixed and .ToLocalString in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't have both of them at the same time, please help.

First Attempt only Shows Decimal Places
`num.toFixed(2).toLocaleString();`

Second Attempt doesn't show anything

```
var total = sum.toLocalString();
document.getElementById("bro123").value = total.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: toFixed() always expect numbers so to user toFixed() you can write Number(total).toFixed(2)

Comment: you are doing backwards `sum.toFixed(2).toLocalString()`  the assing total to div

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code like this

```
var total = sum.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("bro123").value = total.toLocaleString();
```

**toFixed** doesn't work for string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an abstract function that contains the logic you described above, if i understood correctly.
This functions accepts both number & string as parameter, and then always convert it to float with 2 decimal points and in the end to string.

```
function convertToStringWithTwoDecimals(input) {
  return Number.parseFloat(input).toFixed(2).toString();
}

convertToStringWithTwoDecimals('1234.45988'); // input as string
```